# Docker:Base image modification

Tags: docker

I have downloaded tomcat baseimage from dockerhub, when i ran the image scanning, I got a couple of vulnerabilities. So, I am looking for a way to modify the baseimage to fix the below vulnerabilities issue. I am using a docker desktop.

Dockerfile directive 'FROM' check 'not_in' matched against 'example_trusted_base1,example_trusted_base2' for line 'scratch'
Dockerfile directive 'HEALTHCHECK' not found, matching condition 'not_exists' check

Answer (score 0):

If the vulnerabilities are legit, then report to the developers and wait for them to fix the issue in the next latest image.

Or, if you have a fix for the vulnerability, you can create a new image like:

`FROM tomcat:latest RUN <fix_vulnerabilities> ...` 
Then use that image as your base image for applications.